# Incrementing Column of Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge multiple Pandas dataframes to create an aggregate dataframe from them. Part of what I want to do is count how many of the original dataframes have data for a given row. I need those rows to have 0 instead of NaN, but know that if the 'Finish' column contains a 0 then there was no data here originally.

Here's what I have attempted:

```
daytona_stats = pd.merge(entry_list, track1_cut, 
                         on='Driver', how='left').fillna(0)
print(entry_list.head())
print(track1_cut.head())
print(daytona_stats.head())

if daytona_stats['Finish'] > 0:
    daytona_stats['races'] += 1
```

This returns

```
            Driver         ...          avg_quality_passes
0        Joey Gase         ...                         0.0
1   Jamie McMurray         ...                         0.0
2  Brad Keselowski         ...                         0.0
3    Austin Dillon         ...                         0.0
4    Kevin Harvick         ...                         0.0

[5 rows x 6 columns]
           Driver  Finish       ...        Pct. Top 15 Laps  Quality Passes
0   Austin Dillon       1       ...                    40.6              67
1   Bubba Wallace       2       ...                    78.3             161
2    Denny Hamlin       3       ...                    66.7             101
3     Joey Logano       4       ...                    74.9             133
4  Chris Buescher       5       ...                    40.1              52

[5 rows x 5 columns]
            Driver  races       ...        Pct. Top 15 Laps  Quality Passes
0        Joey Gase    0.0       ...                     0.0             0.0
1   Jamie McMurray    0.0       ...                     0.0             2.0
2  Brad Keselowski    0.0       ...                    39.6           133.0
3    Austin Dillon    0.0       ...                    40.6            67.0
4    Kevin Harvick    0.0       ...                    44.0           171.0

[5 rows x 10 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\Personal\Personal_Projects\Daytona_Projections.py", line 48, in <module>
    if daytona_stats['Finish'] > 0:
  File "C:\Users\burusj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1573, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Sample input and full, complete error with traceback please.

Comment: Amended post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
daytona_stats.loc[daytona_stats['Finish'] > 0,'races'] += 1
```

instead of:

```
if daytona_stats['Finish'] > 0:
    daytona_stats['races'] += 1
```

You can read more why it works in the `pandas` [tutorial on indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. I'll read up to understand this better.